# Derivation of Schrödinger's equation

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I recall a famous quote of the late physicist Richard Feynman:

> Where did we get that from? It's not possible to derive it from anything you know. It came out of the mind of Schrödinger.

This quote was with reference to the derivation of Schrödinger's equation. I often found it strange that, to the best of my knowledge, there was no rigourous method to derive Schrödinger's equation. The closest I've come to finding one was in [this paper](http://www.drchristiansalas.org.uk/MathsandPhysics/Research/ADerivationOfSchrodingersEquation/FeynmansDerivation.pdf). Is Feynman's quote still true? Is it not possible to derive Schrödinger's equation from "anything we know." If yes, why is it so widely accepted as the equation that perfectly describes quantum states? Because it coincides with experimental results?

Comment: This may be better suited for the Physics Stack Exchange site, since one can only 'derive' Schrodinger's equation based on physical principles. (One can study it mathematically, but the mathematical interest need not be reliant on it being a description of an actual physical phenomenon.)

Comment: @Semiclassical I posted it on this site because I was interested in knowing whether there was a actual rigourous derivation for it.

Comment: To which I have to respond, a rigorous derivation from _what_? You can certainly find Schrodinger's equation in mathematical contexts, but its meaning as a description of (non-relativistic) quantum mechanics is not something one derives: it is something one theorizes and applies. (One can ask about how it arises as an approximation of quantum _field_ theory, for example, but such will remain a physical argument and not an essentially mathematical one.)

Comment: Déjà vu all over again.

Comment: Perhaps a derivation is the wrong word. Maybe you want an interpretation. I think you can interpret the equation as conservation of energy written as an operator equation.

Comment: What about a mathematical justification ? An argument that is rigorous but based on physical ideas. For example you can start from the classical wave equation and using basic quantum equations ($E=h\nu$) substitute to get Schrodinger.

Comment: http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Freeman_Dyson "Thirty-one years ago [1948], Dick Feynman told me about his "sum over histories" version of quantum mechanics. "The electron does anything it likes," he said. "It just goes in any direction at any speed, forward or backward in time, however it likes, and then you add up the amplitudes and it gives you the wave-function." I said to him, "You're crazy." But he wasn't."

Comment: It is possible, but it requires you to make other assumptions about the behaviour of quantum systems. Why do you find this surprising though? There are many physics equations that cannot be derived, these are known as postulates. You choose postulates because they seem to capture how nature works. Maxwell's equations can't be derived from the perspective of classical electrodynamics (they can be derived from quantum electrodynamics, but then you're just choosing other postulates to begin with). At some point though, you have to choose an equation(s), simply because it seems to work.

Comment: Historically, Einstein energy relation between energy and frequency and DeBroglie hypothesis about the relation between momentum and wave number provides a dispersion relation for a wave. Once you have the dispersion relation you can find what equation yields such relation. DeBroglie found that his relation explains X-Ray experiments which were performed by his brother. The potential introduction is done by a classical argument. However, D. Bohm explains how to introduce the potential in the free equation. People start to believe they were in the right way since it explains new experiments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a post almost identical with yours at here:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/30537/is-the-schr%C3%B6dinger-equation-derived-or-postulated

but there is a much better answer at here:

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/83450/is-it-possible-to-derive-schrodinger-equation-in-this-way/83458#83458

I had the same question myself when I reading Feynman a few months ago.